# Only Linux is installed and still grub menu is being displayed?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub2

I have installed only linux mint 19 on my system. There is no any other operating system installed on my system, yet still grub menu is being displayed.

Though initially after installation, it automatically started without showing grub, but after `sudo apt dist-upgrade` it started to display grub menu on every startup.

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Grub is not just boot manager (one functionality of boot manager is Os selection).
It is Also a **boot loader**.

Boot managers provide chances to give the user some control over the boot process but bootloader does necessary actions to boot the operating system. actually  make the boot process possible.

You can also disable grub menu

[Booting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting)

[BootLoader](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bootloader)

Comment: how can I disable grub menu display during startup?

Comment: change GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT explained https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=225525

Answer (score 0):

You can change it via config

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Just set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` to `true`.

After that run `sudo update-grub` for it to pick up updated config

Answer (score 0):

The GRUB boot menu is not just an operating system selector; it is also a troubleshooting tool.

If you install an updated kernel (possibly as part of a security patch) and it turns out that the new kernel has an incompatibility with your hardware, the GRUB boot menu usually includes at least two or three previous kernel versions: if your system hangs at boot after an update, you can use the GRUB boot menu to boot with an older, known-good kernel version to fix the problem with the latest update (or to uninstall the newest kernel, make a bug report and wait until the distributor fixes it).

There are other things you can do with GRUB too: for example, if you forget the root password, you could gain access to the system in command line mode by specifying some boot options in GRUB.

(Security tip: if the system is a laptop or is in a location that is not physically secure, you probably configure GRUB menu to be password-protected, or otherwise a person with physical access and some Linux knowledge could reset the system and bypass the system password authentication pretty easily.)